# Should exec always be the last line of shell script?

Tags: shell-script, process, exec

I have a shell script that does the following:

```
export FOO=foo           # step 1
/usr/bin/java my-server  # step 2
```

This shell script is launched by a parent program that needs to know the PID of the process started on Step 2. This is currently achieved by running `exec` on the server launch command to replace the shell with command in Step 2. Thus, the PID of the process that runs the script becomes the PID of the “my-server” process.

Now I have to add another command to this shell script that quickly validates the server launched in Step 2. So my program now should look like the following:

```
export FOO=foo                      # step 1
exec /usr/bin/java my-server &      # step 2
/usr/bin/java my-validation         # step 3
```

Can I add Step 3 as shown above? What are the alternatives to this approach?

Comment: By `[launch server]`, do you mean `[launch application]`? Can you show what the actual lines in the script look like so that what you are doing is clear?

Comment: Yes, launch an application. Sure, will edit the question.

Comment: Then yes, that will work as long as the environment variables are being set for the user who is launching and running the application and as long as your validate command is functioning properly. Have you tested it to make sure?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the validate command is functioning properly. Are there any alternatives to this approach that you can suggest?

Comment: You already have a script that handles everything so you can't get much simpler than that. You've verified that it's working properly so there's no need to fix what isn't broken.

Comment: In any case, the third line won't be executed.

Comment: If I change the second line to be `exec /usr/bin/java my-server &` ?

Comment: I edited your question based on my understanding of it;  please check it and fix it if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To combine what the other answer and the comments said, and then add a bit:

- `exec your_command &` doesn’t make sense. 
  The command line will run in an asynchronous subshell,
  and the `exec` will essentially be ignored.

  - That’s a *slight* oversimplification. 
    If we say

    ```
    (command1; command2) &
    ```

    then `command1` and `command2`
    will run (`command2` after
    `command1` completes) in an asynchronous subshell. 
    But if we
    say

    ```
    (exec command1; command2) &
    ```

    then `command1` will run
    but `command2` will not.
- Anything after a correctly formed 
  `exec` command (that doesn't consist only of redirections) in a script will be ignored. 
  Even if the `exec` fails, the shell will exit without running the subsequent lines (one can use `command exec ...` or `bash`'s `execfail` option to prevent `exec` from exiting the shell upon failure).
- if the `exec` runs in a subshell, like in your `exec cmd &` or `exec cmd | cmd2` or `(exec cmd3)`, then only that subshell exits.
- If your validation command needs to know the PID of the server process,
  you may be out of luck.
- Otherwise,
  if your validation command automatically waits a while for the server to start,
  you can do

  ```
  export FOO=foo                      # step 1
  /usr/bin/java my-validation &       # step 1½
  exec /usr/bin/java my-server        # step 2
  ```
- Otherwise, you can do

  ```
  export FOO=foo                              # step 1
  (sleep 10; /usr/bin/java my-validation) &   # step 1½
  exec /usr/bin/java my-server                # step 2
  ```

  Warning: if your “my-server” process terminates quickly,
  then it is quite possible that your script will exit,
  and the parent process will regain control and resume running,
  before your “my-validation” command runs. 
  If the parent process and the “my-validation” command
  both write output to the same place, they may be intermixed.

  But if the parent process isn’t waiting for the script to exit,
  this might not be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

`exec program` replaces the process of the script with the new `program`, so should be used only where that makes sense. That is, the current script goes away and will not be able to run any subsequent commands (unless `exec program` fails).

`exec program` as the last line of a shell script is useful where `program` runs for long periods of time and you do not want a useless shell process dangling around in the process tree until `program` exits. Use `pstree` or other process tools to inspect the difference between:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $$
sleep 9999
```

and

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $$
exec sleep 9999
```

`exec program` is not at all useful if you want to run other shell commands after the `exec`, as those shell commands **are not reached** (unless `exec` fails).

To validate something after launch is actually fairly tricky, as `/usr/bin/java my-server` will take time to launch (and Java can be excruciatingly slow in this regard; I recall one Java process that took upwards of 45 seconds to become available or shut itself down...) and depending on how busy the system is or the scheduler the validation process may run before or after the `my-server` runs. As a kluge you can delay the validation step with something like

```
export FOO=foo
/usr/bin/java my-server &
sleep 10
exec /usr/bin/java my-validation
```

which gives 10 seconds for `my-server` to launch itself, which may or may not be enough depending on how busy the system is and how long `my-server` takes to start. Again, I've seen Java processes take upwards of 45 seconds to start, and that was not on a busy system where the startup time could be even longer. The `sleep` may not be necessary if `my-validation` is intelligent enough to wait for `my-server` to get up and running.

It may make more sense to only start the server:

```
#!/bin/sh
export FOO=foo
exec /usr/bin/java my-server
```

and do the validation that the service is running [via a monitoring framework](https://github.com/kahun/awesome-sysadmin#monitoring), elsewhere.

Yet another approach would be to integrate with `systemd` or some other modern init framework that offers better process control than a shell script does. For example a process can communicate back to `systemd` whether it has started properly, or `systemd` can automatically restart the service under various conditions, and so forth.